# Error " List has no rows for assignment to SObject"

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class

I am doing a wrapper class binding account and its related contact and opp record.

For starters, there is only one Account with the name 'Account1'. 'Account1' only has 1 Contact and
1 Opportunity.

My code is as follows:

```
public class Example1 {

 
public Example1(){
    
    WrapperClass WC1 = new WrapperClass();
    wc1.acc=[Select ID, Name from Account Where Name ='Account1'];
    wc1.con=[Select ID, Name from Contact Where ID = :wc1.acc.id];
    wc1.opty=[Select ID, Name from Opportunity Where ID = :wc1.acc.id];
    system.debug(wc1);
}


Public Class WrapperClass{
    public Account acc;
    public Contact con;
    public Opportunity opty; 
      
} }
```

I am getting the following error

```
Line: 8, Column: 1
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

There's two errors here. In both you Contact and Opportunity query you're `WHERE` clause is incorrect. You're comparing the Contact and Opportunity Ids respectively to the Account Id, which is incorrect. For bother queries, you want `WHERE AccountId = :wc1.acc.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and I found that there is a problem with your code.

The error has occurred because you're trying to match the ContactId/OpportunityId with the AccountId - in the WHERE clause you are using  Id =: wc1.acc.id whereas you have to use  WHERE AccountID =: wc1.acc.id where you're fetching both the Contact and Opportunity.

Here is your code with modifications:-

```
public class Example1 {  
    
    public Example1(){
        
        WrapperClass WC1 = new WrapperClass();
        wc1.acc=[Select ID, Name from Account Where Name ='Account1'];
        List<Contact> cont = [Select ID from Contact Where AccountID = :wc1.acc.id];
        if(cont.size()>0){
            wc1.con=[Select ID, Name from Contact Where AccountID = :wc1.acc.id limit 1];
        }
        List<Opportunity> opp = [Select ID from Opportunity Where AccountID = :wc1.acc.id];
        if(opp.size()>0){
            wc1.opty=[Select ID, Name from Opportunity Where AccountID = :wc1.acc.id limit 1];
        }
        system.debug(wc1);
    }
    
    Public Class WrapperClass{
        public Account acc;
        public Contact con;
        public Opportunity opty;
        
    } 
}
```

Hope this explanation will resolve your query.

Thanks

Akshay